# Upon CICD Pipeline deployment to another environment I get a bad resource error for a Linked Service in ADF. I can't update it or delete it

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory, cicd

I am pushing an ADF factory to another environment via a CICD Pipeline and YAML Config file in Azure Devops. I can successfully deploy but one of my linked services becomes a "bad resource" although it works in the master branch when I published it.

Furthermore I cannot delete this in the target data factory nor can I edit it. Getting the bad resource error. I suspect I need to edit something in the ARM file but I don't really understand this error nor can I find much information on similar.

[image]

`{"stack":"Error: Error: Unable to save [SERVICENAME]. Bad resource\n at Rl.<anonymous> (https://adf.azure.com/app.06b0e174dd8e6fa8.js:1:11274843)\n at Generator.next (<anonymous>)\n at https://adf.azure.com/main.d1fe4ec6f69aa72f.js:1:66326\n at new c`

That when I deploy my ADF to a new environment it succeeds with connections intact or at least that I can fix/edit.

EDIT: Even when I recreate the Linked Service I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is to store all of your connection credentials as secrets in Azure Keyvault then reference that. I am unclear why using the parameters in a linked service do not transfer into the ARM template and this cause it to be a "bad resource" but the Keyvault method translates into ARM correctly and the problem doesn't persist.

Comment: hi TTT, to benefit more users in community, you could look into [this wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to highlight your answer